# String as function and called by other sub class with integer value

Tags: c++, file

I want to create a file with C++ and write something in it. I have two classes, one with a Vererbung::writer(string name) and another subclass called Vererbung1(int zahl). Without the integer it works peferctly but when I want to write the integer to string and paste it after the function it wont work.

this works normally

Vererbung.cpp

```
void Vererbung::Writer(string name)
{
    ofstream text;
    text.open ("test.txt", ios::trunc);

    text <<"write something\n";
    text <<"again2 \n";
    text <<"again 3\n";
    text << name;

    text.close();
}
```

Vererbung1.cpp

```
include "Vererbung.h"


void Vererbung1::Writer(int zahl)
{
    std::ostringstream ostr;
    ostr<< zahl;

    name = "\n"  "Test\n""Test\n""Test\n" ostr.str();

    Vererbung::Writer(name);
}
```

When I run it in main it says that I need a ';' before ostr.str(); how can I fix this, If I want a integer value to string in a file in it?

Comment: Use + to append `std::string` objects.

Comment: You can only use string pasting with string literals, it can't be used to concatenate with variables or expressions.

Comment: @aschepler Post that as an answer.

Comment: ...and fix the comma splice while you're at it

Comment: thanks! yeah i forgot the + ...

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very unclearly stated but, if we assume that `name` is an `std::string`, then:

```
name = "\n"  "Test\n""Test\n""Test\n" ostr.str();
```

This is just a bunch of string literals written next to each other, followed by an `std::string` expression also just randomly floating there in free space.

Your computer doesn't know what you want it to do.

Although you actually *can* concatenate string literals in this way (literals are something like `"hello world"`, but *not* something like `aStringVariable`), that doesn't apply to arbitrary expressions (and you don't even need it where you've used it).

I think that what you meant was this:

```
name = "\nTest\nTest\nTest\n" + ostr.str();
```

I hope that your C++ book teaches this; if not, get a better one.

Comment: also `name` is not declared... maybe better would be `Writer("bla" + ostr.str());`